# Grabbing Array Index with PHP

Tags: php, json, database

I am trying to get a certain value from an array in PHP.

The json returned is

```
string(3017)"[{"userId":"1","0":"1","order":"[
  {
    \"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"AlwaysNew.mp3\",\"album\":\"Oh No!\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"Always1.mp3\",\"album\":\"Fly\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"Always2.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album 2\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"Always3.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album 1\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"Always.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album 4\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"AlwaysNew2.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album Title is Unavailable\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"AlwaysNew3.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album Title is Unavailable\"}]",
    "1": "[{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"AlwaysNew.mp3\",\"album\":\"Oh No!\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"Always1.mp3\",\"album\":\"Fly\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"Always2.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album 2\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"Always3.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album 1\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"Always.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album 4\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"AlwaysNew2.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album Title is Unavailable\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"AlwaysNew3.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album Title is Unavailable\"}]",
    "user_email": null,
    "2": null
  },
  {
    "userId": "2",
    "0": "2",
    "order": "[{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"AlwaysNew.mp3\",\"album\":\"Oh No!\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"Always1.mp3\",\"album\":\"Fly\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"Always2.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album 2\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"Always3.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album 1\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"Always.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album 4\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"AlwaysNew2.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album Title is Unavailable\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"AlwaysNew3.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album Title is Unavailable\"}]",
    "1": "[{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"AlwaysNew.mp3\",\"album\":\"Oh No!\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"Always1.mp3\",\"album\":\"Fly\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"Always2.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album 2\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"Neville-Peter-Always3.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album 1\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"Always.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album 4\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"AlwaysNew2.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album Title is Unavailable\"},{\"image\":\"undefined\",\"song\":\"AlwaysNew3.mp3\",\"album\":\"Album Title is Unavailable\"}]",
    "user_email": null,
    "2": null
  }
]"
```

I'm decoding the results returned from my database with

```
$order = json_decode($json,true);
```

And it returns

```
array(2){
  [
    0
  ]=>array(6){
    [
      "userId"
    ]=>string(1)"1"[
      0
    ]=>string(1)"1"[
      "order"
    ]=>string(622)"[{"image":"undefined","song":"AlwaysNew.mp3","album":"OhNo!"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always1.mp3","album":"Fly"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always2.mp3","album":"Album2"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always3.mp3","album":"Album1"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always.mp3","album":"Album4"},{"image":"undefined","song":"AlwaysNew2.mp3","album":"AlbumTitleisUnavailable"},{"image":"undefined","song":"AlwaysNew3.mp3","album":"AlbumTitleisUnavailable"}]"[
      1
    ]=>string(622)"[{"image":"undefined","song":"AlwaysNew.mp3","album":"OhNo!"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always1.mp3","album":"Fly"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always2.mp3","album":"Album2"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always3.mp3","album":"Album1"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always.mp3","album":"Album4"},{"image":"undefined","song":"AlwaysNew2.mp3","album":"AlbumTitleisUnavailable"},{"image":"undefined","song":"AlwaysNew3.mp3","album":"AlbumTitleisUnavailable"}]"[
      "user_email"
    ]=>NULL[
      2
    ]=>NULL
  }[
    1
  ]=>array(6){
    [
      "userId"
    ]=>string(1)"2"[
      0
    ]=>string(1)"2"[
      "order"
    ]=>string(622)"[{"image":"undefined","song":"AlwaysNew.mp3","album":"OhNo!"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always1.mp3","album":"Fly"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always2.mp3","album":"Album2"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always3.mp3","album":"Album1"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always.mp3","album":"Album4"},{"image":"undefined","song":"AlwaysNew2.mp3","album":"AlbumTitleisUnavailable"},{"image":"undefined","song":"AlwaysNew3.mp3","album":"AlbumTitleisUnavailable"}]"[
      1
    ]=>string(622)"[{"image":"undefined","song":"AlwaysNew.mp3","album":"OhNo!"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always1.mp3","album":"Fly"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always2.mp3","album":"Album2"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always3.mp3","album":"Album1"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always.mp3","album":"Album4"},{"image":"undefined","song":"AlwaysNew2.mp3","album":"AlbumTitleisUnavailable"},{"image":"undefined","song":"AlwaysNew3.mp3","album":"AlbumTitleisUnavailable"}]"[
      "user_email"
    ]=>NULL[
      2
    ]=>NULL
  }
}
```

When I use `$song = $obj[0]['order'];` I get the full Order String:

```
string(622) "[{"image":"undefined","song":"AlwaysNew.mp3","album":"Oh No!"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always1.mp3","album":"Fly"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always2.mp3","album":"Album 2"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always3.mp3","album":"Album 1"},{"image":"undefined","song":"Always.mp3","album":"Album 4"},{"image":"undefined","song":"AlwaysNew2.mp3","album":"Album Title is Unavailable"},{"image":"undefined","song":"AlwaysNew3.mp3","album":"Album Title is Unavailable"}]"
```

Which is great but is there a way to get just the first object `{"image":"undefined","song":"AlwaysNew.mp3","album":"Oh No!"}`?

My php code:

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php' );
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_email = $current_user->user_email;

$db = new PDO("mysql:hostname=db","root","root");

$st = $db->prepare("SELECT * from wp_songs order by userId");

$st->execute();
$obj = $st->fetchAll();
$json = json_encode($obj);
$order = json_decode($json,true);
$song = $obj[0]['order'];



if ($_POST['submit']) {
        var_dump($song);
}
```

Comment: You can use ```current``` to get a single element from an array. Thus ```$order = current(json_decode($json,true));``` might do what you need.

Comment: Can you share a full example of your json?

Comment: Hi @Jono20201 I've edited the post and added the json returned from the database.

Comment: @user2573699 Do you control the source providing the json? The json provider is double JSON'ing resulting in escaped JSON.

Comment: @Jono20201 I did a fetchAll() from the database and did a json_encode on what was returned from the fetchAll(). Did I complicate things? I've only ever used PHP to just connect to the database and do the rest in javascript, never to work with the json in PHP.

Comment: @user2573699 Maybe you could add your PHP to the question?

Comment: @Jono20201 I have added my full php code. Thanks for taking the time out to help.